# Use Nginx Ingress sequentially in Kubernetes to expose service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-networking

I have three namespaces in my GKE cluster: `nginx-global, nginx-a, app-a`.

```
kubectl create namespace nginx-global
kubectl label namespace nginx-global namespace-type=nginx-global

kubectl create namespace nginx-a
kubectl label namespace nginx-a project=a
kubectl label namespace nginx-a namespace-type=nginx

kubectl create namespace app-a
kubectl label namespace app-a project=a
kubectl label namespace app-a namespace-type=apps
```

Now I installed two nginx ingress controllers in the namespaces `nginx-global` and `nginx-a`:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update

helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace nginx-global --set controller.scope.namespaceSelector="namespace-type=nginx"
helm install ingress-nginx-a ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace nginx-a --set controller.scope.namespaceSelector="namespace-type=apps,project=a" --set controller.service.type="ClusterIP" --set controller.ingressClassResource.name="nginx-a"
```

And I create a dummy app in the last namespace `app-a`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo1
  namespace: app-a
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 5678
  selector:
    app: echo1
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo1
  namespace: app-a
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo1
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo1
        image: hashicorp/http-echo
        args:
        - "-text=echo1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5678
```

Now, it is my aim to expose the dummy app via the `ingress-nginx` LoadBalancer by going through the `ingress-nginx-a` ClusterIP in the middle.

For this I was first creating an A record at Cloudflare `*.example.com` pointing to the LoadBalancer IP. Then I used the following Ingress rules:

```
# For pointing from the first nginx ingress (ingress-nginx) to the second nginx ingress (ingress-nginx-a)

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx2-ingress
  namespace: nginx-a
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.example.com"
    http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: ingress-nginx-a-controller
              port:
                number: 80

#For pointing from the second nginx ingress (ingress-nginx-a) to the echo service

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
  namespace: app-a
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-a"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "test.example.com"
    http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: echo1
              port:
                number: 80
```

However, I simply get the usual "404 Not Found" nginx error. Do you know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx ingress might create cluster role bindings with same name in all installations. Check

```
kubectl get clusterrolebindings | grep ingress
```

So if one of them is colliding with the other this might cause other one to be disfunctional. This is also true for other cluster wide resources

Comment: Hi @Furkan, this is what comes then: `ingress-nginx                                          ClusterRole/ingress-nginx                                          8m14s
ingress-nginx-a                                        ClusterRole/ingress-nginx-a                                        7m52s`

Comment: Okay it seems that is not the problem

Comment: In case you happen to have another idea, I would definitely appreciate it as there might be a shortcut to reach it, but which I simply do not figure out properly.